# Trying to copy down formulas from previous row after inserting values from formula (all on same new row)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an existing function that inputs values from a function on to the last row that is blank. This function 1) grabs data from 6 cells on a sheet that is used as a form, 2) switches over to another sheet where the data is stored, then 3) creates a new row and inputs those specifc 6 cells in Columns A through F. This has worked great, but rather than just write those values on the new row in Columns A through F, I also need it to copy down the formulas from the previous row for columns G through J.  Here is the existing code for my function:

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry Form"); 
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");  
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("C3").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C4").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C5").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C8").getValue()]];
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues(values);
}
```

From the last line, this clearly enters the data into the last empty row. But rather than just enter those six values in Column A through F pulled from the other sheet (from "Data Entry Form"), I would like to also have it pull down the formulas in the sheet "Data" from the previous row that are currently in Columns G through J.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you looked into `Range.getFormulas()`? You can see reference [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas).

Comment: Could you share a sample spreadsheet with use please?

Comment: Thanks! Let me try the range.getformulas() approach and see if I can work this in to the last line, after it writes the values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on *how* you want to retrieve the formulae from your sheet, you have the following options:

- `getFormula()` - this will return the formula in the A1 notation for the top-left cell of the range, or an empty string if the cell is empty or doesn't contain a formula;
- `getFormulas()` - the same behavior as `getFormula`, however, the results will be stored in a 2D array ;
- `getFormulaR1C1()` - this will return the formula in the R1C1 notation for a given cell, or `null` if none;
- `getFormulasR1C1()` - the same behavior as `getFormulaR1C1`, however, the results will be stored in a 2D array.

Therefore, depending on your needs and how your spreadsheet looks like, you can make use of any of the methods suggested above.

#### Reference

- [Apps Scrip Range Class - getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula);
- [Apps Scrip Range Class - getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas);
- [Apps Scrip Range Class - getFormulaR1C1()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformular1c1);
- [Apps Scrip Range Class - getFormulasR1C1()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulasr1c1).